# Connect to a table inside foreach and check if a record exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Started to develop a asp.net C# MVC application, using entity framework and database first.
I am new to all of the concepts.
I have 2 tables in the database: "Lote" and "Cargas". I have created the controllers and views for both. My table "Lote" has a Primary Key named: lot_numero and this works as a Foreign Key in table "Carga".

I have a view where I am printing all the data in table "Carga". You can check the code below.

```
@model IEnumerable<Deltas.carga>
@*@model IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Deltas.carga>>*@

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cargas por Lote";
    @*var dbAccess = Database.Open("FornosDeltaEntities");*@
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @*@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")*@
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <p> 
            Número de Lote:@Html.TextBox("searchString")
            <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar por lote"/>
        </p>
    }
</p>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
           NºLote
        </th>
        <th>
            NºCarga
        </th>
        <th>
            NºCemento
        </th>
        <th>
           TPE
        </th>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Acções</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    @*var numLoteCurrente = @item.lot_numero;*@
        <tr>
        <td>
           @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lot_numero)*@
           @*@numLoteCurrente*@
           @Html.ActionLink(item.lot_numero, "Details", "Lote",new { id = item.lot_numero },null)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.cga_numero,"Details",new{id = item.cga_numero}, null)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cem_numero)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tpe_numero)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ConverteData)</td>
        <td>
           @* @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.cga_numero }) |*@
            @Html.ActionLink("Detalhes", "Details", new { id=item.cga_numero })  @*|
           @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.cga_numero })*@
        </td>
    </tr>
}
 </table>
<p>  @Html.ActionLink("Back","Index") </p>
```

You can see right after the foreach loop that I create a link related to the item.lot_numero allowing me to check the lot_numero details. And this is working.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
 <tr>
  <td>
    @Html.ActionLink(item.lot_numero, "Details", "Lote",new { id = item.lot_numero },null)
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Right now, what I would like to do before creating the link, it would be: go to the table "Lote" and check if that number exists in the database. If exists, then I would print the link; if not, I would Just print the item.lot_number without link.

My problem is: how to connect to that table inside foreach and check if there is any record with the item.lot_numero.

Thanks in advance for your attention and possible help.

Regards,

### Aganju

My classes are like this:

```
namespace Deltas
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class lote
    {
        public string lot_numero { get; set; }
        public string ope_numero { get; set; }
        public string tpe_nome { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> lot_peso_total { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> lot_total_cargas { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> lot_cargas { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> lot_estado { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> lot_data { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> lot_hora { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> lot_peso_prp { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> lot_peso_total_cargas { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> lot_cem_num_utilizacoes { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> lot_cem_tipo { get; set; }
        public string lot_datahora { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace Deltas
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    public partial class carga
    {
        public string cga_numero { get; set; }
        public string cem_numero { get; set; }
        public string lot_numero { get; set; }
        public string tpe_numero { get; set; }
        public string buj_numero { get; set; }
        public string ope_numero { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> for_numero { get; set; }
        public string ret_numero { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> cga_carga { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> cga_parte_lote { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> cga_data_in_forno { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> cga_hora_in_forno { get; set; }
        public string cga_tmp_in_forno { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> cga_data_out_forno { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> cga_hora_out_forno { get; set; }
        public string cga_tmp_out_forno { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> cga_estado { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> cga_cem_num_utilizacoes { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> cga_ret_total_utilizacoes { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> cga_ret_num_utilizacoes { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> cga_ret_lim_utilizacoes { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> cga_buj_total_utilizacoes { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> cga_buj_num_utilizacoes { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> cga_buj_lim_utilizacoes { get; set; }
        public string cga_lot_tmp_out_forno { get; set; }
        public string cga_lot_tmp_in_forno { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> cga_lot_cem_num_utilizacoes { get; set; }
        public string cga_datahora { get; set; }
        public DateTime ConverteData { get { return DateTime.ParseExact(cga_datahora, "yyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); }}
    }
}
```

---

I am not sure if they have navigation properties. Could you provide a brief explanation about it?

Thanks in advance,
Aganju

Comment: Could you show your classes, or tell us if they have navigation properties ? Anyhow, the best way would be to load the related `Lote` with each `Carga` (from or in your controller), than just check if Carga has a Lote in your view (without going to the db).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class and a method for checking the lot no like below

```
public class NewClass
{
public  bool CheckLot(int id)
{
//do the logic
}
}
```

you can create an instance of this class from the model itself for accessing the method **CheckLot**

```
@model IEnumerable<Deltas.carga>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cargas por Lote";
    var obj=new NewClass();
}
```

and then you can check inside the loop like below for displaying the link

```
<td>
if(obj.CheckLot(item.lot_numero))
{
 @Html.ActionLink(item.lot_numero, "Details", "Lote",new { id = item.lot_numero },null)
}
</td>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks JEMI, your idea helped me. I have finally accomplished my goal. It works fine now! Regards, Aganju!

Answer (score 0):

MVC stands for Model, View, Controller where:
 **Model** describe the way you want to model your data extracted from database
**Controller** handles all the necessary business logic 
**View** display all the data that you processed thru **Controller**

I find this tutorial very useful for someone who is new to this area : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4